# check if the input String name is in the text file or not, i dont know why it is not work

Tags: java

My text file include:
Tom,Ben,Kevin,Marry,Lok,Erick

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {      
       Scanner sc = new Scanner (new FileReader("name.txt"));
       String Name;
       Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);       

       System.out.println("Enter a name:");
       Name= in.nextLine();

       String name = null;
       while(sc.hasNext())
       {
           name= sc.next();
       }
       if (Name.equals(name))
       {
           System.out.println("Yes");
       }       
       else
       {
           System.out.println("No");
       }
```

i don't know how to fix it, help please.

Comment: Might want to change your tag from 'javascript' to 'java' so the right people see your question

Answer (score 0):

It is becuase you first run through all the file and after that you check on the last word.

You need to change it to this code:

```
while(sc.hasNext())
{
    name= sc.next();   
    String [] Str=name.split(",");

    for(int i = 0; i < Str.length(); ++i)
    { 
       if (Name.equals(Str[i]))
       {
           System.out.println("Yes");
       }       
       else
       {
           System.out.println("No");
       }       
    }
 }
```

Comment: when i input Tom,Ben,Kevin,Marry,Lok,Erick, it will print "Yes", but when i input just one name, it will print "No". how can i input just one name , it will print "Yes"

Comment: while(sc.hasNext())
       {
     int i=0;
        name= sc.next();   
        String [] Str=name.split(",");
        
        if (Name.equals(Str[i]))
        {
            System.out.println("Yes");
        }       
        else
        {
            System.out.println("No");
        }
        if (i<Str.length)
        {
         i++;
        }
        
     }

Comment: please write it in your question as EDIT

Comment: @LokChan , just improve it a little, look at the answer part